# UITextField not calling editingChanged on device but works on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, ios-simulator

I have a `UITextField` sets up in `UICollectionViewCell`. I've used closure to declare the UITextField as follows:

```
var nameTextField: UITextField = {
    let textfield = UITextField()
    textfield.backgroundColor = .clear
    textfield.borderStyle = .line
    textfield.placeholder = "Name"
    textfield.textColor = UIColor.white
    textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textfieldDidChangeValue), for: .editingChanged)
    textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textfield
}()
```

It is supposed that when textfield's content is changed, the `.editingChanged` event would be called and then call function `textfieldDidChangeValue`. It works well in iOS simulator, but not working in my real iPhone 12 Pro device. It is my first time to face problem of different behavior between simulator and real device. What is the possible fix for it? Thank you.

Xcode: Version 13.3.1 (13E500a)

iOS simulator: iOS 14.7 iPhone 13 pro

real device: iOS 14.7.1 iPhone 12 pro

Comment: I guess you can try different device, or different os version- its working fine on ios 15 (real device), try changing selector to  textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textfieldDidChangeValue(textfiled:)), for: .editingChanged)   @objc func textfieldDidChangeValue(textfiled:UITextField)
    {
        print("changed")
    }

Comment: I tried your suggestion accordingly. But it is not working @Sunil Bhosale

Comment: But I found a method that works. When calling `addTarget` at `init` of UICollectionViewCelll, everything works fine. But I don't understand why it matters. Maybe the UICollecrtionViewCell's variable is declaring too early and cannot find the target function `textfieldDidChangeValue` yet in my original code?

Comment: since your complete code is not available to see it is hard to find whats wrong, although your posted code is completely fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out why it is not working to `addTarget` when declaring the `UITextField`. Because the `self` is not ready when target is added. I should make the variable `lazy` to guarantee `self` is available.

```
lazy var nameTextField: UITextField = {
    let textfield = UITextField()
    textfield.backgroundColor = .clear
    textfield.borderStyle = .line
    textfield.placeholder = "Name"
    textfield.textColor = UIColor.white
    textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textfieldDidChangeValue), for: .editingChanged)
    textfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textfield
}()
```